# How can I change Photoshop's Extrusion Depth unit of measurement?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, modeling

I have created the following image, by heading to 'Windows > 3D > Extrusion > Create' within Photoshop:

[image]

I would now like to reduce its Extrusion Depth, using Millimeters as the unit of measurement.  At present, the Extrusion Depth is set at 224 as per the below screenshot:

[image]

I can only assume this is a Pixel Measurement.  Is this the case and if so, is there a way to change its Unit of Measurement?

Comment: I just realized you can actually change the units, I edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the 3D extrusion you can see in the Properties panel that the unit for Extrusion Depth is indeed px:

[image: Properties panel]

Also in the little preview window that pops on top of the canvas:

[image: 3D preview]

But you'll get an error if you try to type a different unit in the Properties panel. You need to click on the **Coordinates** button and there you can change the units:

[image: coordinates]

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have just modified my question to include an additional screenshot.  As you can see, the `px` unit is not included.  In fact, it does not allow me to enter any unit of measurement.  I have also gone to the 'Coordinates' area, where the 'Units' field is not present.  Do I need to alter some settings elsewhere, in order to generate the 'Units' option?

Comment: I have just used a new version of Photoshop, where I can see the 'Units' field.  I guess Photoshop simply did not offer this feature, within an older version I was using.